# How to force mapping of domain names of https sites to ip addresses of http sites by editing hosts file in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, browser, ssl, connection, hosts-file

I'm editing hosts file in Windows 7,what I want is to map domain name of sites that uses https to IP address of an unsecured site that obviously uses http. For instance, I have the IP address of 'pornhub.com', I edit the hosts file and assign the IP address to 'Facebook.com' domain name. Now if I try to type facebook.com in the browser I should get to pornhub site(couldn't find a name of unsecured site cause all popular sites that came up in my mind are secure sites that uses https ). 
But what happens is that all browsers say "connection is not private". And it worked like a charm for me when I assigned IP address of an unsecured site to another unsecured site.

Could someone explain how to do the same with secure sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You don't** – because it really has *nothing to do* with the IP address. Part of TLS (as used by HTTPS) is that the server presents a proof that the *domain name* belongs to that server.

For example, when you connect to Facebook, their servers present a certificate showing "I'm authorized to use `www.facebook.com`" (along with a digital signature). Then your browser compares the certificate against the address (URL) that was entered by you, i.e. `https://www.facebook.com/`. It doesn't need to verify IP addresses at all.

The certificate is only usable if the server has a corresponding private key (which it never reveals to visitors – it's only used to make signatures), and it has to be issued by one of the CAs (certificate authorities) recognized by the browser.

So if TLS does its job correctly, then the only way to present a fake website (as is sometimes done by developers trying to troubleshoot something, or by corporations trying to snoop on employees) is to create your own private CA, issue your own certificates, *and* most importantly install the CA certificate onto all clients' computers, so that they'll "trust" your fake website certificates.

For development, there are various tools which do this, such as Fiddler and Burp Proxy.

Comment: so basically it can work? If I have the IP address of unsecured site, and I edit the hosts file and assign to any https site, the owner of the computer will be redirected to the unsecured site? I have no wrong intentions in my mind, just want to do it.

Comment: @Ari - Have you tried?

Comment: @Ari: Mmmmmaybe but generally no. If their browser uses https _from the beginning_ (especially if the site has active HSTS), then they _will_ get an error about your fake server, and you can't bypass that (except via custom CA). If and _only_ if their browser tries to use regular http, they're vulnerable and the redirect _will_ work. (this is how sslstrip works – it relies on people forgetting to use https.)

Comment: So what about hacking a router which also acts as a DNS server and editing its DNS? I've also learned that before Windows 7, hackers would create a site that runs a script that changes your computer's HOSTS file, so next time you try to visit the popular sites, you get redirected to similar looking site (phishing).

Comment: Once again, changing the way IP addresses are resolved **has no effect** on HTTPS. Either the server is capable of proving its identity or it's not.

Comment: So a set up server by anyone, can prove that it is a any popular site server by doing a little hard work? Like you mentioned via custom CA?

Comment: Not exactly. Like I _also_ mentioned, a custom CA only works if the visitors first manually install and trust that CA. So, basically, only if the user does a manual override. "Yeah, I know it's a fake site, let me visit it anyway!"